# Check If Page Will Load (Rails/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I've seen a few posts to for methods to check if a route exists, but at this stage there are many routes on my site whose pages have errors (working on it!). I was wondering if there's a way to check not only if a route exists, but also that it will load properly if loaded.

If there's a way to do this in Javascript, that could work too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the usage of controller tests using [Rspec](http://rspec.info/)?

With the use of [Rspec](http://rspec.info/), you can write tests for all your routes, to be sure that they return the right `http status`.

An example of a `route test` will be as follow:

```
describe "GET index" do
  it "returns http success" do
    get :index
    expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
  end
end
```

Something like the above could then be written to cover all your routes in individual controllers, where the `expectation` would be set to the right status normally expected (`success`, `failure`, `redirect`, or whatever) and when something goes out of order, it is easily discovered.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

with jquery you can check the status code of a given url like following

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: some_url,
    complete: function(request, xhr, settings){
       if(request.status === 200){
       // do something
       }else if(request.status === 500){
       // do something
       }else if(request.status === 404){
       // do something
       }
    }
  });
});
```